# Can't get form data using HTMX. Always returns None when using hx-get

Tags: python, html, flask, htmx

I want to use hx-get to send my form data to a route where I can create an image. The problem is I don't know how to get the values from a form using HTMX. What do I use in HTMX to get the values from my select tags?

```
<div id="edit_pizza" class="edit_pizza" hx-get="/custom-image" hx-trigger="every 2s" hx-target="#edit_pizza" hx-include="[name='pizza_form']"></div>
```

```
<div class="pizza_list" style="text-align: center;">
    <form action="pizza-process-custom" id="pizza_form" class="pizza_form" name="pizza_form">
        <p>Username: {{username}}</p>
        <label class="labels" for="lineart">Lineart:</label>
        <br>
        <select class="selects" id="lineart" name="lineart" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-get="/outline-image" hx-target="#outline_image">
            <option value="1">Black Outline</option>
            <option value="2">Flat Outline</option>
            <option value="3">Detailed Outline</option>
        </select>
        <div id="outline_image">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="labels" for="colour">Colour:</label>
        <br>
        <select class="selects" id="colour" name="colour" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-get="/shading-image" hx-target="#colour_image">
            <option value="1">Flat Colours</option>
            <option value="2">Shading</option>
            <option value="3">Highlights</option>
        </select>
        <div id="colour_image">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label class="labels" for="topping">Topping:</label>
            <br>
            <select class="selects" id="topping" name="topping">
                {% for topping in toppings %}
                {% if topping[1] == "Nothing" %}
                <option value="{{topping[0]}}," selected>{{topping[1]}}</option>
                {% else %}
                <option value="{{topping[0]}},">{{topping[1]}}</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="edit_pizza" class="edit_pizza" hx-get="/custom-image" hx-trigger="every 2s" hx-target="#edit_pizza" hx-include="[name='pizza_form']"></div>
        <input class="sub" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
@app.route('/custom-image')
def custom_image():
    lineart = request.form.get('lineart')
    colour = request.form.get('colour')
    toppings = request.form.getlist('topping')
    topping_string = ""
    for topping in toppings:
        topping_string += topping
    toppings = topping_string.split(",")
    toppings.remove(toppings[-1])
    print(toppings, lineart, colour)
    pizza_image(1, lineart, colour, None, toppings)
    return render_template(OUTLINE_HTML, image_name="view_pizza")
```

I tried using hx-include and hx-vals but I'm unsure how to properly use them. Every time I try doing this my toppings, colour and lineart values always equal to an empty string or None.

Comment: use hx-post if you want to read values from a form. if you are using hx-get then read the values from querystring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)