# How do I fix this error in my Python/React app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I always get error when I try to send user inputs (.pptx file and entry) from my React app to my Python file. My Python should also get the info, make GPT create a response and send it back. This is what my JS console says:
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. apimain.js:12:32
Response from the server: undefined

And this is what my Python page shows: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvgZH.png)

My main.py:

```
import openai
from openaiapikey import openaiapikey
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from pptx import Presentation
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000"], allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"], methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"], supports_credentials=True)

def open_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as infile:
        return infile.read()

def extract_pptx_slides(pptx_path):
    presentation = Presentation(pptx_path)
    slides_info = []

    for i, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
        slide_info = {"slide_number": i + 1, "text": "", "images": []}
        
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                slide_info["text"] += shape.text + " "
            elif shape.has_image:
                image_stream = BytesIO(shape.image.blob)
                slide_info["images"].append(image_stream.read())

        slides_info.append(slide_info)

    return slides_info

openai.api_key = openaiapikey

def analyze_presentation(presentation_path, question):
    """
    Analyze a presentation using OpenAI's GPT-4 with Vision model. 

    :param presentation_path: The file path to the presentation to analyze
    :param question: A question about the presentation to send to the model
    :return: The analysis result from the model along with extracted slides information
    """

    presentation_content = open_file(presentation_path)
    slides_info = extract_pptx_slides(presentation_path)

    content = {"type": "presentation", "data": presentation_content, "slides": slides_info}

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-4-vision-preview", 
        messages=[
            {
                "role": "user", 
                "content": [
                    {"type": "text", "text": question},
                    content,
                ],
            }
        ],
        max_tokens=300
    )

    return {"result": response.choices[0].message["content"], "slides": slides_info}

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def process_form():
    industry = request.form["title"]
    presentation_path = request.files["body"]
    question = f"This is a presentation and industry. Based on its content, what can be improved? The industry is {industry}"

    result = analyze_presentation(presentation_path, question)
    print(result)
    return jsonify({"result": result})
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

```
export default class APIService {
    // Insert an article
    static InsertArticle(body) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload`, { 
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import APIService from '../components/apimain';

const Hero = () => {
  const [industry, setIndustry] = useState('');
  const [presentationPath, setPresentationPath] = useState(null);

  const handleIndustryChange = (event) => {
    setIndustry(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePresentationPathUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setPresentationPath(file);
  };

  const handleGenerate = () => {
    if (industry && presentationPath) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('title', industry);
      formData.append('body', presentationPath);

      APIService.InsertArticle(formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Response from the server:', response);

          if (response.error) {
            console.error('Server error:', response.error);
          } else {
            // If needed, navigate to the Response component
            // navigate('/response');
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error sending data to the server:', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Please fill in both industry and upload a presentation file.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <section className="border-t my-4 p-8">
              <div className="my-10 mx-40 flex justify-between max-md:mx-10 max-sm:flex-col max-sm:w-56 max-sm:ml-28">
                <button className="py-3 px-12 bg-[#7e7b7b] rounded-md m-4">New</button>
                <button className="py-3 px-12 bg-[#7e7b7b] rounded-md m-4">PR1</button>
              </div>

              <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                <label htmlFor="industry" className="mb-2 flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                  Your Industry:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="industry"
                  name="title"  // Added change: Set the name attribute to "title"
                  value={industry}
                  onChange={handleIndustryChange}
                  className="bg-gray-50 border ml-4 border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-40 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                  placeholder="Your Industry"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  accept=".pptx"
                  onChange={handlePresentationPathUpload}
                  className="hidden"
                  id="pptxFileInput"
                />
                <label htmlFor="pptxFileInput" className="flex justify-between my-5 w-56 py-3 px-10 rounded-md bg-[#74a8ca] cursor-pointer">
                  Upload .pptx
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                <button onClick={handleGenerate} className="flex justify-between my-5 w-40 py-2 px-8 rounded-md bg-[#74a8ca]">
                  Generate
                </button>
              </div>
            </section>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

I tried to make user input his .pptx and his industry and then it would make a response and print it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Comment: You can either send a `FormData` object or a JSON string. In your case, send the `FormData` object as `body` in your `fetch` call. Do not convert to JSON.