# How do I add a pdfPages that I created in python to my flask interface?

Tags: python, flask, pdf, pdfpages

I have created a python program that takes a few inputs and then creates several plots and saves them in one big pdf using pdfPages. Now I want to create a local web interface using flask which opens this pdf to make it easily viewable. I do not have a lot of Flask experience so I don't know what the nicest way to do this is?
Also, using request.data doesn't seem a good option to me, since I have a pdf I would like to open and as I understand it request is used for data like jsons or strings and not entire pdfs.

My current idea would be to call the function and let it create and save the plots and then open the pdf in Flask. However, this doesn't work for me. Is there a better way to do it? If not, can you recommend tips how I can make this run?

My current code looks something like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():

    param1 = str(input('Enter the first parameter: '))
    param2 = str(input('Enter the second parameter: '))
    plotting_function(param1=param1, param2=param2)

    file_path=os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/plots' + "/plots_for_param_" + param1 + ".pdf" 
# This is the name of the file and the path where it is being stored

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as static_file:
        return send_file(static_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, if I run this code I get an error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'`

After the responses from @Detlef, I have improved my code so it looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    param1 = str(input('Enter the first parameter: '))
    param2 = str(input('Enter the second parameter: '))
    plotting_function(param1=param1, param2=param2)

#The name is the name of the file that is being created by the plotting function 
   name = str("plots_for_user_" + param1 + ".pdf")
   return download_file(name,param1)

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def download_file(name,param1):
# /plots/plots_ specifies the path of the folder that the created file that is to be loaded is saved into, starting from the current path where the flask application is running
# name is the name of the file
    return flask.send_from_directory(
        '/plots/plots_' + param1 + '_/', name, as_attachment=True
    )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, with this I run into the issue of th Url not being found and I have no idea where to start, since the error message is so unspecific. Any help greatly appreciated!!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have read the article and unfortunately do not understand how that will solve my problem, as request.data is used for handling data "sent" to the flask app. However I want to first run a function that creates the data and then simply open it.

Comment: Your approach with `str(input('...'))` can only be used for command line programs. In Flask, using it throws an error message, as you learned. The article describes how you can request input from an HTML form, a URL parameter or another type in Flask. This allows you to receive user data and then use it for your purposes.

Comment: Although little is known about your application, I think you want to generate the PDFs first and then publish them to Flask. To create the files, you can simply include the call at the beginning of your Flask application script. You can easily serve files with a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) for a path and [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory). A file is thus made available for download in the specified path.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have tried to include your suggestions, however am still stuck. I included the current code at the end of my original suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know so far, two inputs from the user are required to create a PDF.

In my very simplified example, a form is displayed which allows the user to make entries. The form is sent to the server via POST request, where the entries are queried based on the defined attributes for the names of the input fields. Now the function `plotting_function(param, path)`, which I don't know, is called, which probably creates the PDF. Based on the path information provided in your example, the generated PDF should then be downloaded automatically.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    request, 
    render_template_string, 
    send_from_directory
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import datetime
import os 
import tempfile

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(PLOTS_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'plots'))
os.makedirs(app.config['PLOTS_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

def plotting_function(path, name, param2):
    # Create the PDF file.
    with PdfPages(path) as pdf:

        # Generate sample data.
        for i in range(1,5):
            fig = Figure()
            ax = fig.subplots()
            ax.plot([1, i])
            pdf.savefig(fig)

        # Set metadata for the PDF file.
        d = pdf.infodict()
        d['Title'] = f'{name.capitalize()}s PDF Example'
        d['Author'] = 'Rosarosa'
        d['Subject'] = 'How to create a multipage pdf file and set its metadata'
        d['Keywords'] = 'PdfPages multipage keywords author title subject'
        d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
        d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # When the form is sent, user input can be 
        # requested based on the name.
        param1 = request.form.get('param1')
        param2 = request.form.get('param2')
        if param1 and param2: 
            # If the input is valid, a temporary directory is created 
            # and the function is called.
            
            plotsdir = app.config['PLOTS_FOLDER']
            with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=plotsdir) as tmpdir:
                file = f'plots_for_user_{param1.lower()}.pdf'
                path = os.path.join(tmpdir, file)

                plotting_function(path, param1, param2)

                # The file will be downloaded.
                return send_from_directory(
                    tmpdir, 
                    file, 
                    as_attachment=True
                )

    # When the page is accessed, a form is displayed for user input.
    return render_template_string('''
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="param1">Param 1</label>
                <input id="param1" name="param1" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="param2">Param 2</label>
                <input id="param2" name="param2" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    ''')
```

Keep in mind that, as already mentioned, this example is very minimal and should be modified and expanded based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this has been helpful. However, even when adapting the code to my specific requirements, I still get a ```UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail``` and a ``` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!' ``` Do you have any idea what a solution may be? I've pretty much used your exact code

Comment: In a web framework like Flask it is not possible to start a GUI. This is the reason why the error message appears. But that doesn't stop you from generating the images with matplotlib and saving them in a folder.

Comment: @Rosarosa I have expanded my example. You can now see how it is possible to add a number of different diagrams to a PDF without launching a GUI. The PDF is then downloaded and all existing data is deleted.

Comment: Thank you. However, I think there may have been a misunderstanding regarding the nature of my question. I already have python code that saves the pdf including the plots, now I want to display this pdf in my web framework, my original question aimed at exactly that: How do I display the saved pdf?

Comment: My code at least shows you how you can get around the error message. But I agree with you that we are unclear about how the result should look and work. Do you just want to have a kind of directory listing where you click on a link and the respective file is displayed? Should the file be displayed as a whole in the browser or embedded in another page? I need to know more about what you want so I can help you.