parsing webhook information to fetch specific parts in python
I have a code that listens for a post to be sent
It receives the post as
    {"description": "Test Call", "map_code": "", "details": "", "cross_street": ""}

It will print this using the following
def return_response():
    Dic = request.json;
    data = json.dumps(Dic)
    print(data)

I have also been able to print it using
print(request.json);

To my attempts i have not been able to convert this from the dictionary/lists to specific parts such as
print('description')
print('details')

*** FUll CODE UPDATE
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/my_webhook', methods=['POST'])
def return_response():
    Dic = request.json;
    data_str = json.dumps(Dic)
    print(Dic.keys())
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav('alert.wav')
    play(song)
    ## Do something with the request.json data.
    return Response(status=200)
if __name__ == "__main__": app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Thank you for any guidance to come.

hi, instead of json.dumps(Dic) use data  = json.loads(Dic). Then you can use data['description'] and etc.

Hello changing the code to Dic = request.json;     data = json.loads(Dic)     print(data['description']) and get error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

ah, sorry, make sense. Dic = request.json() will return parsed data in the dict format. Thus Dic['description'] should get the values.

data_dict = request.json() (dictionary) and data_str = json.dumps(data_dict) (string). So data_dict['description'] should work

data_dict = request.json() errors with TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Changed it to def return_response():     Dic = request.json;     data_str = json.dumps(Dic)     print(Dic['description']) Now i get this error which i think is a step forward KeyError: 'description'

run print(Dic.keys()) to see available keys

Could you please share lines of code related to the post request? Are you a client or server side? If a client side you must be doing smth similar to:
response = requests.post(url, ..) then Dic = response.json() and then Dic['description']

If you are a server side accessing request depends on the framework. For example in flask you usually access keys using request.args.get('description')

print(Dic.keys()) only showed 2 keys It appears that the description key is enclosed in the 3rd { "something" : { "somethingelese" { "description" } } } It is in flask on the server side set up as a webhook end point original post updated with full code

got it. check this post for more hints on how to access data keys in Flask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request There are several options from here depending if the post request was sent by a form or if body was encoded with json (then  application/json included in request header). I would also consider possibility that request on the client side was formed with errors (thus you have dictionary in dictionary ...)

I'm so glad it was helpful!

Thanks to help from Johnny I was able to work through the problem.
The information being sent doesn't have the content/json tag so force must be true.
Then there are sub layers to the information such as { unit 1 { unit 2{ unit 3
To get to the information i needed to call each layer
data = request.get_json(force=True)
    name = data.get('alert', '')
    name2 = name.get('normalized_message', '')
    discription = name2.get('description', '')

Only then was the final call the post data
and
print('discription' 

now returns the information from the post
Once i could print it i could pass it to other parts of the application.
